# Script that will write down to file, names, permissions and modification time of files in directory that are exactly 3 characters long

Tags: bash

I`m trying to write script that will write down to file, names, permissions and modification time of files in directory that are exactly 3 characters long

But without using [awk] or [sed] commands

Comment: Is `find` allowed? Is `perl` allowed? What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: find might be allowed
The only method I know to check for 3 characters long files is 
ls|awk 'length($0)==3{print $0}'

How would it look like with ' [find] with (write to file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
#! /bin/bash
set -eu
dir=$1
out=$2

for file in "$dir"/??? ; do
    if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
        stat -c'%n %A %y' "$file"
    fi
done > "$2"
```

Run it with two parameters, the directory to search and the output file name.

Answer (score 0):

If your `find` has the `-printf` flag.

```
find . -type f -name '???' -printf '%M %t %f\n'
```

Your requested/desired output.

```
find . -type f -name '???' -printf '%f %M %TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %Tz\n'
```